# easiest way of converting asp.net gridview to telerik radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

In my existing project if i purchase telerik controls what is the easiest way for migrating from gridview to radgrid

Comment: Inlude telerik dll and also register at page level, then Use radgrid thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik guys have a page dedicated just for that.

Read this: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/migration/defaultcs.aspx

They also have a  [White Paper](http://www.telerik.com/documents/ComparisonSheets/controls.pdf)<sup>(pdf)</sup> that compares the features (Page 14)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Naveen But my question is in my existing project i am having hundreds of pages with gridview.Only way to change them is manually replacing gridview with rad grid or there is any other option?